# Colorize a Region

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

My searches have lead nowhere on this one.

I have a `MeshRegion` (say, a 2D manifold embedded in 3D) and would like to plot a function on it: such that the color of a point at (x,y,z) is determined by a function of the coordinates.

I have found `MeshCellStyle`, which allows me to specify flat color per cell, but does give access to coordinates for a full `ColorFunction`-style. There's also `RegionPlot3D`, which might work (using `(x,y,z) ∈ ℛ`) for a full-dimensional submanifold but when passed a lower-dimensional object embedded in 3D the sampling algorithm never hits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can extract mesh coordinates and polygons of your `MeshRegion` and use them to construct a [`GraphicsComplex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html) with [`VertexColors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html).

For example:

```
mreg = DiscretizeRegion[
       ImplicitRegion[-3 y - 4 x y^2 + 4 x z^2 + 4 x^2 z + 2 y^2 z^2 + z^3 == 0, 
         {x, y, z}],  MaxCellMeasure -> .001]
```

[image]

```
mc = MeshCoordinates[mreg];

polys = MeshCells[mreg, 2];

f[x_, y_, z_] := x y + z; 

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], 
  GraphicsComplex[mc, polys, VertexColors -> (Hue[f@##] & @@@ Rescale[mc])]}, 
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Use `VertexColors -> (Opacity[.7, Hue[f@##]] & @@@ Rescale[mc])` to get

[image]