# `VertexColors` seems to blend colours unevenly

Tags: functions, color

`VertexColors` seems to blend colours unevenly, often with a "stripe" between vertices. Compare:

```
mix4[n_, col_] := 
    ArrayPlot[Table[Blend[{#, #2}, t], {t, 0, 1, 1/n}] & @@@ 
    Thread[Table[Blend[{#, #2}, t], {t, 0, 1, 1/n}] & @@@         
    {#, Reverse@#2} & @@ Partition[col,2]], Frame -> False];

(*
cols = RandomColor[4];
Grid[{{
Graphics[ Polygon[CirclePoints[4], VertexColors -> Part[cols, {3, 4, 1, 2}]]], mix4[100, cols]
}}]
*)
```

[image]

I would like to create polygons without the "stripe" that is characteristic of `VertexColors`. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: This happens because the system uses linear interpolation over triangles. One (tedious) way to avoid it is to use a higher resolution than just the 4 corner points, and specify the colour at each point. One way is `ArrayPlot`, as you show here. Another way is to use `DensityPlot`, or to use `DiscretizeRegion` on your polygon and specify the colour at each internal vertex.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16168/quirk-in-vertexcolors-interpolation-when-displaying-polygon

Answer (score 5):

Modifying @kglr 's code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229509/colorize-a-region), I have made a slight improvement, thanks to @Szabolcs ' comment:

```
n=5; cols={Red,Green,Blue,Yellow,Magenta};
mreg=DiscretizeRegion[Region[ Polygon[CirclePoints[n]]], MaxCellMeasure -> .5];
mc = MeshCoordinates[mreg];polys= MeshCells[mreg,2];

Grid[{{
Graphics[ Polygon[CirclePoints[n], VertexColors ->Join[cols,{Blend[cols]}]]],
Graphics[{EdgeForm[],  GraphicsComplex[mc, polys, VertexColors ->Join[cols,{Blend[cols]}]]}]
}}]
```

[image]

The rather long running time for

```
n=5;c=30; cols={Red,Green,Blue,Yellow,Magenta};pts=CirclePoints[n];
array=Select[Flatten[Table[{a,b},{a,-1,1,1/c},{b,-1,1,1/c}],1],
RegionMember[Polygon[N@CirclePoints[n]],N@#]&];
allpts=Flatten[Table[{Blend[cols,1/If[#==0,.001,#]&@
EuclideanDistance[t,#]&/@pts],Point@t},{t,array}],1];
Graphics[{PointSize[1./c],allpts, 
EdgeForm[{White,Thickness[.1]}],Opacity[0], 
Polygon[1.1N@CirclePoints[n]]}]
```

[image]

gives closer to desired result though.

Just for fun:

```
hex[cols_,n1_]:=Module[{n,c,k,pts,array},
n=6;c=3.5;k=(n1-1)c;pts=CirclePoints[n];
array={(#-k)/k,(#2+2)/k}&@@@#&/@DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Table[CirclePoints[
{Sqrt[3] (1 j + k - 2 ) + Sqrt[3] (1 j + l - 2 ),3 k - 2 - 3 l}, 
{2, Pi/2}, 6], {j, #}, {k, #}, {l, #}],2],Sort@#==Sort@#2&]&@n1;
Graphics[{Flatten[Table[{Blend[cols,1/If[#==0,.001,#]&@
EuclideanDistance[Mean@t,#]^2&/@pts],Polygon@t},{t,array}],1]}]];

(*hex[{Red,Green,Blue,Yellow,Magenta,Orange},5]*)
```

[image]